# Google sports widget: displaying women schedule by default

Tags: google-search

When searching for a sporting event on Google, say Wimbledon, Google displays the schedule of the upcoming games.

I've noticed that, by default, Google displays the *women's singles* schedule (second tab) rather than the first tab, i.e. *men's singles*. Any reason why? Any way to change this behaviour?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can't really believe that the volume of searches is favoured toward women? Objectively, the standard of tennis is simply higher in the men's game than women so naturally people gravitate toward those who are best at a sport.

(Before you get bent out of shape, of course I'm not saying women tennis players aren't exceptional at the sport. It's just that the top women would only barely seed in the top 200 men in the world and that's well documented and accepted, even by Serena Williams.)

I would believe its far more likely that this is a Google 'woke' ideological response to the ridiculousness that we're seeing in 2021.

(regarding the numbers posted, of course you would have higher viewership for that ladies singles match, in the US, as it was an American playing. The men's single match, as stated, had almost double the viewership. I agree with user0 that Google may be slanted towards women, in the US, based on those numbers but I'm not in the US and have the same search outcome which indicates a choice rather than algorithmic.)

Comment: indeed 100% woke!

Answer (score 1):

The workaround would be to search:

```
Wimbledon men
```

[image: 0]

And the reason could be based on stats for popularity/viewership (in the US)

Comment: I've also noticed that by adding "men" to the query it gets me to the male tab, but I'd like to keep my query to the bare minimum. Also,  men's tennis is much more popular than women's, thus my lack of understanding.

Comment: I believe Google would disagree with you otherwise it would show males tab. its like football and search for UEFA. who cares about women UEFA? not Google coz they don't even have a widget

Comment: here could Google gain inspiration: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8G897.png - another source says: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4khv4.png ... anyway, back to the topic: there is no URL parameter to switch tabs on the widget so the only option is to have "men" in the search query

Answer (score 1):

It's 100% programmed like that. Women's tennis is no where near as popular as men. It's an attempt to get people to watch it more because yay women.... Women's sports are simply not entertaining because of the physical limitations. Simple as that.